# How to check from within a Gradle file if a task has been or has not been excluded?

Tags: gradle

In a Gradle file is the following configuration:

`publishing {
  publications {
    if (os == 'osx') {
      nebulaIvy(IvyPublication) {
        artifact('build/final/java_plugin-linux-x86_64/linux-x86_64.exe') {
          classifier 'linux-x86_64'
          extension 'exe'
          type 'exe'
        }
      }
    }`

The Linux binary is built through the task `buildInDocker`. If the `buildInDocker` task is excluded (eg `gradlew -x buildInDocker`), that part of the configuration shouldn't be done. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getExcludedTaskNames(): `!project.getGradle().startParameter.getExcludedTaskNames().contains('buildInDocker')`.